# Cluster services in RHEL 4.8

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux

We have two of our Servers running on RHEL 4 Update 8, using Cluster suite to run common services. Currently due to some constraints we have no plans to upgrade the OS. But we have some maintenance activity on the servers, for which we need to stop and start the cluster services on both nodes.Kindly help to know which services to restart. In RHEL 5 and above we usually just restart "cman" and "rgmanager" which would take care of everything. But not sure for RHEL4.8. So kindly help. This is the cluster configuration that we have on the nodes:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cluster alias="Airguard_stc" config_version="1" name="Airguard_stc">
  <fence_daemon clean_start="0" post_fail_delay="0" post_join_delay="3"/>
 <clusternodes>
 <clusternode name="eir1-c" votes="1" nodeid="1">
 <fence>
 <method name="1">
  <device name="eir1-ilo"/>
  </method>
  </fence>
  </clusternode>
 <clusternode name="eir2-c" votes="1" nodeid="2">
 <fence>
 <method name="1">
  <device name="eir2-ilo"/>
  </method>
  </fence>
  </clusternode>
  </clusternodes>
  <cman expected_votes="1" two_node="1"/>
 <fencedevices>
  <fencedevice agent="fence_ilo" hostname="eir1-ilo" login="aws_ilo"     name="eir1-ilo" passwd="airguard"/>
  <fencedevice agent="fence_ilo" hostname="eir2-ilo" login="aws_ilo" name="eir2-ilo" passwd="airguard"/>
  </fencedevices>
 <rm>
 <failoverdomains>
 <failoverdomain name="EIR" ordered="0" restricted="0">
  <failoverdomainnode name="eir1-c" priority="1"/>
  <failoverdomainnode name="eir2-c" priority="1"/>
  </failoverdomain>
  </failoverdomains>
 <resources>
  <ip address="172.24.159.44" monitor_link="1"/>
  <ip address="172.24.159.45" monitor_link="1"/>
  <fs device="/dev/mapper/mpath0p3" force_fsck="0" force_unmount="1"     fsid="27623" fstype="ext3" mountpoint="/cache_app" name="cache_app" options=""     self_fence="0"/>
  <fs device="/dev/mapper/mpath0p5" force_fsck="0" force_unmount="1" fsid="34677" fstype="ext3" mountpoint="/postgres" name="postgres" options="" self_fence="0"/>
  <script file="/etc/init.d/cache_cacheha" name="cacheha"/>
  <script file="/etc/init.d/postgresha" name="postgres-script"/>
  </resources>
 <service autostart="1" domain="EIR" name="cache" recovery="relocate">
  <ip ref="172.24.159.44"/>
  <fs ref="cache_app"/>
  <script ref="cacheha"/>
  </service>
 <service autostart="1" domain="EIR" name="postgres" recovery="relocate">
  <ip ref="172.24.159.45"/>
  <fs ref="postgres"/>
  <script ref="postgres-script"/>
  </service>
  </rm>
  </cluster>
```

Also Can you please give me any link for RHEL4.8 Cluster Suite Management ?

Answer (score 1):

Before everything, RHEL 4.8 is already declared EOL by Redhat. Secondly I'm lucky to have found some documentation finally https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/pdf/Cluster_Administration/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-4-Cluster_Administration-en-US.pdf

which gives me what I need (basically all individual services need to be restarted instead of only cman):

5. Stop the cluster software on the two running nodes by running the following commands at each
   node in this order:

   ```
   a. service rgmanager stop, if the cluster is running high-availability         services
   (rgmanager)
   b. service gfs stop, if you are using Red Hat GFS
   c. service clvmd stop, if CLVM has been used to create clustered volumes
   d. service fenced stop
   e. service cman stop
   f. service ccsd stop
   ```
6. Start cluster software on all cluster nodes (including the added one) by running the following
   commands in this order:

   ```
   a. service ccsd start
   b. service cman start
   c. service fenced start
   d. service clvmd start, if CLVM has been used to create clustered         volumes
   e. service gfs start, if you are using Red Hat GFS
   f. service rgmanager start, if the cluster is running high-availability services
   (rgmanager)
   ```